# How to hide or remove dynamically added marker in Ngmap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I have a form along with the map(ngMap),After filling the form and inserting the marker on map, if i click submit it will save. but again if i go to add one more, the marker will be already there at the place of  previous co-ordinates. if i reload the page manually, the marker will  gone  out of map. how to remove or hide without manual reloading of page.
**HTML**

```
  <ng-map zoom="13" center="{{coordinates.lat}},{{coordinates.lng}}" map-type-id="TERRAIN">
                    <marker></marker>
                    <shape name="polygon" on-click="drawPolygon()" paths={{rectangle}} stroke-color="#ff3232" stroke-opacity="0.8" stroke-weight="2" fill-color="#ff4c4c" fill-opacity="0.35">
                    </shape>
                    <drawing-manager on-overlaycomplete="insertMarker()" drawing-control-options="{position: 'TOP_CENTER',drawingModes:['marker']}" markerOptions="{icon:'http://www1.durban.gov.za/beachwater/images/markers/orange-dot.png'}" drawingControl="true" drawingMode="null">
                    </drawing-manager>
                </ng-map>
```

**Controller**

```
    $scope.drawingControlOptions = {
        position: 'TOP_CENTER',
        drawingModes: ['polygon', 'marker']
    };
    $scope.placesCounter = 0;
    $scope.insertMarker = function(e) {
        if (e.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
            $scope.placesCounter++;
            if ($scope.placesCounter > 1)
                e.overlay.setMap(null); //disable marker from diplaying ..
            var pos = e.overlay.getPosition();
            $scope.markercoordinates = pos.toString();
        }
    };
```

and also i have tried like this in success promise, but didn't work

```
$scope.positions= [];
place.coordinates=$scope.positions[0];
```

and as i have used ui-router, i tried to reload the page programmaticaly like this `$state.transitionTo('dashboard.places.list', null, { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true });` 
that also didn't work. Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is discussed in [github](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/issues/553) and this issue has been fixed with ngMap version 1.17.1.